# The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: vb.net

Please help me When i execute this linq to sql command its given an error "The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type."

1. 0 Records in my Commotidy Table
2. I want generate manual number and get the last CommodityCode

### My Code as follow,

```
Dim QRecordCount = From RC In cntxtCommodity.CommodityMasters _
                                 Where RC.CommodityCode <> 0 _
                                Select RC.CommodityCode

                LastCommodityCode = QRecordCount.Max() + 1
```

---

VB.NET 2008

Suhaib

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your code with this example:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim cntxtCommodity As New List(Of CommodityMasters)

        cntxtCommodity.Add(New CommodityMasters With {.CommodityCode = 34})
        cntxtCommodity.Add(New CommodityMasters With {.CommodityCode = 1})
        cntxtCommodity.Add(New CommodityMasters With {.CommodityCode = 234})
        cntxtCommodity.Add(New CommodityMasters())

        Dim LastCommodityCode = cntxtCommodity.Where(Function(rc) rc.CommodityCode.HasValue AndAlso rc.CommodityCode > 0).Max(Function(rc) rc.CommodityCode)

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class CommodityMasters

    Public CommodityCode As Nullable(Of Integer)

End Class
```

Basically, the above is supposed to deal with nullable integers (`CommodityCode`) which should stop you getting exceptions on that part. I'm not 100% sure if it solves all your problems though, with no records in the database. Try it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind Jason, still it couldn't shortout

Comment: @Suhaibnm - Can you try declaring the variable `LastCommodityCode` as `Nullable(Of Integer)` before calling the line `LastCommodityCode = QRecordCount.Max() + 1`? Possibly you have `LastCommodityCode` declared as an `Integer`.

Comment: i used above type but error appear 
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.